# selenium, how to get emoji from whatsapp chat messege and print that emoji in our terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, whatsapp, emoji

how to get emoji from whatsapp chat messege and send print that emoji in our terminal or save in a list (python)  in  selenium ? , i know how to get text messeges from whatsapp chats and print in our terminal or saved them as a list in python selenium . but that only works for text messages , code  prints a blank (space) or sometimes a new line instead of emoji

```
chats = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("message-in") 
for i in range(0, len(chats)):
    text_messege = chats[i].find_element_by_class_name("i0jNr").text 
    print(f"{str(i)} : {text_messege}")
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML ?

Comment: yes @cruisepandey this is of first emoji   = <img crossorigin="anonymous" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" alt="" draggable="false" class="b75 emoji wa i0jNr selectable-text copyable-text" data-plain-text="" style="background-position: -60px -40px;">

Comment: @cruisepandey  this is of second emoji  = <img crossorigin="anonymous" src="/img/d07f9aca6938f691b840f97dd1cd67dd_w_1749-64.png" alt="" draggable="false" class="_2UdhN _1xeoG i0jNr selectable-text copyable-text" data-plain-text="" style="visibility: visible;">

Comment: @cruisepandey  basically i want to webscrape an emoji

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, so if you use

```
img[data-plain-text][crossorigin='anonymous']
```

`css selector` it will list all the emojis.

```
chats = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("img[data-plain-text][crossorigin='anonymous']")
for chat in chats:
    print(chat.get_attribute('alt'))
```

This should basically print all the emojis.

Comment: thks bhai , it worked . actually I made a code which sends deleted message to sender when a message is deleted (basically to see delted messages of whatsapp) and it only worked for text and i  was looking for this for emoji since 2,3 months .thanks once again

Comment: bro actually it doesn't work with send_keys().                                                    `type = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-tab="6"]')
type.send_keys(chat.get_attribute('alt'))` this gives error ==  Message: unknown error: ChromeDriver only supports characters in the BMP

Comment: so i had to use this code using module pyperclip                                                      `pyperclip.copy(chat.get_attribute('alt'))
type.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "V")`     by using this actually it works but it sends twice in whatsapp typebar but prints only once in terminal for a particular emoji                for eg it prints this in terminal ""  and same code types this in whatsapp       typebar ""

Comment: also i am not able to append that emoji in list , when that emoji is appended in list , and after printing list it gives a list with elements ="None"

Comment: No you shouldn't do like that. First print what that get_attribute('alt') is printing, also the xpath data-tab is that correct ?

Comment: Also can you create a new ticket for the new issues ? That will have large audience to help you. Tag selenium, I'll get notification also

Comment: actually i am new to stack overflow by new ticket you mean new quetion post right? i have posted a new question this is link  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68793739/selenium-how-to-send-emoji-to-sender-in-whatsapp-with-send-keys)

Comment: that xpath with data tab is correct it is of typing bar where we type our message in whatsapp chat