# selenium ,how to send emoji to sender in whatsapp with send_keys()?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, whatsapp, emoji

selenium ,how to send emoji to sender in WhatsApp with send_keys()? . i dont want to send emoji by clicking on that emoji button ,but i want to like just copy the emoji which has been sent to us in text message of whatsapp and send that same emoji to sender . i have tried this as helped by @cruisepandey

```
chats = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("img[data-plain-text][crossorigin='anonymous']")
 for chat in chats:
     print(chat.get_attribute('alt'))
```

this above code prints all the emojis of a chat. But by using this code this gives an error of

```
chats = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("img[data-plain-text][crossorigin='anonymous']")
     for chat in chats:
         print(chat.get_attribute('alt'))
         type = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-tab="6"]')
         type.send_keys(chat.get_attribute('alt'))
```

this code gives an error  = Message: unknown error: ChromeDriver only supports characters in the BMP

```
 chats = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("img[data-plain-text][crossorigin='anonymous']")
 for chat in chats:
     print(chat.get_attribute('alt'))
     type = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-tab="6"]')
     pyperclip.copy(chat.get_attribute('alt'))
     type.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "V")
     time.sleep(1)
```

i tried this code  to send emoji but this  by using this actually it works but it sends twice in whatsapp typebar but prints only once in terminal for a particular emoji for eg it prints this in terminal "" and same code types this in whatsapp typebar ""   .      CAN ANYONE HELP ME WHY IT IS PRINTING TWICE IN WHATSAPP TYPEBAR BUT ONLY ONCE IN TERMINAL ??? i also want to append that emoji into a list ,but when appending that emojis ,after printing list ,it gives a list with elements ="None" .        This is complete code

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
 from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
 from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
 from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions  
 import time
 import pyperclip
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\PRANAV PATIL\Downloads\chromedriver.exe')
 driver.get(r'https://web.whatsapp.com/')
 searchbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 
     10).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 
     "//div[@id='side']//div//div//label//div//div[@contenteditable='true']")))
 searchbox.send_keys('')  #enter your sender's name
 searchbox.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
 time.sleep(2)
 chats = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("img[data-plain-text][crossorigin='anonymous']")
 for chat in chats:
     print(chat.get_attribute('alt'))
     type = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-tab="6"]')
     pyperclip.copy(chat.get_attribute('alt'))
     type.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "V")
     time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding that typing twice : Instead of `type.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "V")`, try like below. It worked for me.

```
type.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+"v")
```

Comment: this worked for me  type.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+"v") thks @pmadhu

Comment: this code  --> `chats = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("img[data-plain-text][crossorigin='anonymous']")
for chat in chats:
    print(chat.get_attribute('alt'))`       is code  is printing all emojis means of sender's and ours also. How to do if we want only to print sender's emojis? hint = sender's emoji has class="message-in" and our messages have class="message-out" actually i dont know much about css selector

Comment: @PranavPatil - I would use this xpath `//div[contains(@class,'message-in')]//img` to get all the emojis from the sender.

Answer (score 0):

So basically, you want to `send_keys` to `type`

Did you try this :

```
type = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-tab="6"]')
type.send_keys(chat.get_attribute('alt'), Keys.RETURN)
```

**Update 1 :**

Looks like you cannot simply send special character like emoji to chromedriver, try changing your browser (change to Firefox and see if that helps) should help you past this issue.

also, if you wanna stick with Chrome, you can give it a try like this :

```
JS_ADD_TEXT_TO_INPUT = """
  var elm = arguments[0], txt = arguments[1];
  elm.value += txt;
  elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
  """
type = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-tab="6"]')
driver.execute_script(JS_ADD_TEXT_TO_INPUT, type, chat.get_attribute('alt'))
```

**Update 2 :**

**Using FireFox :**

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = "D:\geckodriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
try:
     searchbox = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='copyable-text selectable-text']")))
     searchbox.send_keys('Anvesh')  # enter your sender's name
     searchbox.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
     print('search was successful')
except:
     print('there were some error while searching for name')
     pass

time.sleep(2)
chats = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("img[data-plain-text][crossorigin='anonymous']")
for chat in chats:
    print(chat.get_attribute('alt'))
    type = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-tab="6"]')
    type.send_keys(chat.get_attribute('alt'))
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: that only gave error of that BMP something  Message: unknown error: ChromeDriver only supports characters in the BMP

Comment: this is error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\PRANAV PATIL\Desktop\qr\emoji.py", line 30, in <module>
    type.send_keys(chat.get_attribute('alt'))
  File "C:\Users\PRANAV PATIL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 477, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,

Comment: File "C:\Users\PRANAV PATIL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\PRANAV PATIL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\PRANAV PATIL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace

Comment: no its actually continuation of above erroe still left error stackover is not giving much space for comments and still more error is left how to share screenshots in this?

Comment: ` JS_ADD_TEXT_TO_INPUT = """
  var elm = arguments[0], txt = arguments[1];
  elm.value += txt;
  elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
  """
chats = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("img[data-plain-text][crossorigin='anonymous']")
for chat in chats:
    print(chat.get_attribute('alt'))
    type = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-tab="6"]')
    type.send_keys(chat.get_attribute('alt'))
    driver.execute_script(JS_ADD_TEXT_TO_INPUT, type, chat.get_attribute('alt'))
print("done")` actually its giving same error  is this code right? @cruisepandey

Comment: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: ChromeDriver only supports characters in the BMP
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.131)
this is the last part of error @cruisepandey

Comment: actually this code is printing all emojis means of sender's and ours also. How to do if we want only to print sender's emojis? hint = sender's emoji has class="message-in"  and our messages have class="message-out" actually i dont know much about css selector